# Iterar con objeto AngularFirestoreCollection en Ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-framework

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo mostrar la información contenida en la imagen adjunta, porque lo he intentado de muchas formas pero no hay manera.

Estoy usando cloud firestore, y de momento obtengo lo siguiente:

```
interface HourTask {
  inicio: string;
  fin: string;
}

todo: Observable<HourTask[]>;

 this.todo = this.asf.collection<HourTask>('extraHours/SAW5riljv0EAU1bp1Dm6/Fecha', ref => {
  return ref;
}).snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      //console.log(a);
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as HourTask;
      // Me gustaría poder devolver evento, inicio y fin de cada tarea. Adjunto foto
      return { event, inicio, fin };
    })
  });
```

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura del error en WebStorm:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura cuando lanzo la app:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No queda claro en la pregunta lo que quieres conseguir o qué es lo que te falla: ¿Tu componente no obtiene los datos? ¿La llamada a firebase falla?

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. He modificado la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución al final fue la siguiente:

```
this.todoCollection = this.asf.collection('extraHours/SAW5riljv0EAU1bp1Dm6/Fecha');
this.todoCollection.snapshotChanges().subscribe(todoList => {
    this.todo = todoList.map(item => {
        const data = item.payload.doc.data() as HourTask;

        return {
            inicio: data['Inicio'],
            fin: data['Fin']
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, me alegro que encontrases tu respuesta y la compartieses con el resto de la comunidad. ¿Podrías explicar qué cambiaste y cómo (y dónde) iría este código? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En tu función map tienes lo siguiente:

```
actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
  const data = a.payload.doc.data() as HourTask;
  // Me gustaría poder devolver evento, inicio y fin de cada tarea. Adjunto foto
  return { event, inicio, fin };
}
```

Veo dos problemas:

- Declaras una constante `data`, donde guardas el objeto `HourTask`, pero luego no lo usas para devolver los valores.
- Viendo la imagen cuando depuras, tu definición de la interfaz HourTask no coincide con lo que hay en `data`.

En tu función tendrías que hacer algo como

```
actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as HourTask;
      const keys= Object.keys(data); // ['Indianos', 'Sardina']
      return keys.map((key)=> ({ event: key, inicio: data[key].Inicio, fin: data[key].Fin}));
    }
```

Comment: Buenos días.En primer lugar, muchas gracias por contestar.
La función la he dejado así y cuando depuro me funciona, pero en el editor de código (uso Webstorm) me sale un error:
actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as HourTask;
          const keys= Object.keys(data);
          return keys.map((key)=> ({
            event: key,
            inicio: data[key]['Inicio'],
            fin: data[key]['Fin']}));
        })

Añado una captura del error en el mensaje original.
Tampoco me muestra info cuando lanzo la app (añado captura)